# Multi language in xamarin.form shared project

Tags: xamarin.forms

[No option to add resource file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvMSe.png)How to create multi language application in xamarin shared project using visual studio 2017 because i am not able to create resource files in shared project.

Comment: Have you searched for a solution? What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/localization/

Comment: yes i have tried, but not able to find any solution...

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck! Xamarin just published a blog post detailing exactly how to do this.

[Blog post details here](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-languages-to-your-apps-with-xamarin-and-multilingual-app-toolkit/)

It talks about using the [Multilingual App Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308) to provide language support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i have just added a image in question as i am not able to add any resource file in my project

Comment: Must be an issue with your Visual Studio setup as I can add a resource fie to my Xamarin Forms app. Try running a repair.

Comment: Is there any way that i can use multi language in an offline application..  as multilingual uses  "Azure Cognitive Service configuration".